# Is it bad practice, security-wise, if user could know the primary key id of items

Tags: mysql, database, security, encryption, xss

I am populating a page with a list of items from DB (lets say main.htm - each item has a link, and opening a link will display the content of the item.

I am using ajax to open the items. For performance reasons, I have added data attribute of their ID to each item in main.htm. so if main.htm has 15 items listed, each item will have a data-id, e.g. item 1 has data-id =1, item 2 has data-id=2

and data-id will correspond to the ID column (primary key) in the Database.

Is this a bad practice, security-wise? if yes, why?

Or is it better practice to encrypt the numbers and instead of id, assign the encrypted id, such as xY4lf3K which would decrypt to 1000 in DB

Comment: It may be insecure if you don't check who is accessing the item. A user's profile edition page for example...

Comment: it's only insecure insofar as it will let people fairly easily 'guess' about items they can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be an insecure way to go, just as long as you keep in mind to:

1. ALWAYS escape & validate user inputs (remember, a $_GET param is a user input, not only $_POST);
2. If the resource identified by the ID is for a specific user, check if that is the user accessing it.

Otherwise, no problems there.